# React hooks: Dynamically mapped component children and state independent from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am gathering posts (called `latestFeed`) from my backend with an API call. These posts are all mapped to components and have comments. The comments need to be opened and closed independently of each other. I'm governing this mechanic by assigning a piece of state called `showComment` to each comment. `showComment` is generated at the parent level as dictated by the Rules of Hooks.

Here is the parent component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { getLatestFeed } from "../services/axios";

import Child from "./Child";

const Parent= () => {
    const [latestFeed, setLatestFeed] = useState("loading");
    const [showComment, setShowComment] = useState(false);

    useEffect(async () => {
        const newLatestFeed = await getLatestFeed(page);
        setLatestFeed(newLatestFeed);
    }, []);

    const handleComment = () => {
        showComment ? setShowComment(false) : setShowComment(true);
    };

    return (
        <div className="dashboardWrapper">
            <Child posts={latestFeed} showComment={showComment} handleComment={handleComment} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Parent;
```

`latestFeed` is constructed along with `showComment`. After `latestFeed` comes back with an array of posts in the `useEffect` hook, it is passed to the child show here:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


const RenderText = ({ post, showComment, handleComment }) => {
    return (
        <div key={post._id} className="postWrapper">
            <p>{post.title}</p>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
            <Comments id={post._id} showComment={showComment} handleComment={() => handleComment(post)} />
        </div>
    );
};

const Child = ({ posts, showComment, handleComment }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map((post) => {
                 <RenderPosts posts={posts} showComment={showComment} handleComment={handleComment} />;
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Child;
```

However,  whenever I trigger `handleComments`, all comments open for all posts. I'd like them to be only the comment that was clicked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to use a single state where you claim you want multiple independent states. Define the state directly where you need it.

In order to do that, remove

```
const [showComment, setShowComment] = useState(false);

const handleComment = () => {
    showComment ? setShowComment(false) : setShowComment(true);
};
```

from `Parent`, remove the `showComment` and `handleComment` props from `Child` and `RenderText`, then add

```
const [showComment, handleComment] = useReducer(state => !state, false);
```

to `RenderText`.

Comment: Oh man. I screwed up. Before i kept getting an error about there being more hooks than the last render. But constructing the state at the lowest child is working great now.

Comment: Never seen useReducer before. thanks man

Comment: @ThirdGhostHand the error about there being more hooks than the last render would be caused by doing `posts.map((post) => RenderPosts({ ... }))` instead of `posts.map((post) => <RenderPosts ... />)`.

Comment: Oh wow. I was doing that. Had that fixed the last time i asked this question. Thanks again!